# How can i perform a rest request in Powershell with Azure endpoint?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

I am trying to perform the following request

```
 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$rgname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$siteName/instances?api-version=2022-03-01 -Method GET -Headers $authHeader
```

but get the error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client  with object  id <obj_id>  does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/instances/read' over  scope
```

Any idea on what may be causing this ?

Comment: What RBAC roles you currently have?

Comment: How can i check that ? I currently have 2 subscriptions , on one it works fine on the other it doesnt ?

Comment: Go to that **other** subscription -> Access Control (IAM) -> View my access like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/kN45xmv.png)

Comment: It has only 1 , Contributor   Grants full access to manage all resources, but does not allow you to assign roles in Azure RBAC, manage assignments

Comment: the other has Owner Grants full access to manage all resources, including the ability to assign roles in Azure RBAC

Comment: Could you include code like how you generated token from powershell?

Comment: If it's via service principal, you need to assign required role to that application before generating token.

Comment: Yes it is via a service principal , I will add the code in the question

Comment: Which role do i need to assign to the application ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249410/discussion-between-sridevi-and-tracey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one Azure AD application named **`WebApp`** and granted **API permission** like below:

[image]

To get the access token, I ran the **same script** in PowerShell as you like below:

```
$tenantId = <tenantID>
$applicationId = <appID>
$secret= <secret>
$param = @{
        Uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token? 
 api-version=2020-06-01";
        Method = 'Post';
        Body = @{ 
            grant_type = 'client_credentials'; 
            resource = 
      'https://management.core.windows.net/'; 
            client_id = $applicationId; 
            client_secret = $secret
        }
   }
$result = Invoke-RestMethod @param
$token = $result.access_token
```

**Output:**

[image]

When I ran the below script to perform the following request, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
$subscriptionId = <subscriptionID>
$rgname = <rgname>
$siteName = <appservicename>
$authHeader= @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $token)}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$rgname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$siteName/instances?api-version=2022-03-01 -Method GET -Headers $authHeader
```

**Output:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to assign **`role`** with *Microsoft.Web/sites/instances/read* permission in it to your application like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> App Services -> Your App Service -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment***

[image]

You can assign **`Website Contributor`** role to your application by selecting it as below:

[image]

After selecting the application, click on **Review + assign** as below:

[image]

Now I generated the **token** again and got response successfully by running ***same request*** as below:

```
$subscriptionId = <subscriptionID>
$rgname = <rgname>
$siteName = <appservicename>
$authHeader= @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $token)}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$rgname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$siteName/instances?api-version=2022-03-01 -Method GET -Headers $authHeader
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can also assign general roles like `Reader` or `Contributor` or `Owner` roles to your **Azure AD application** based on your requirement by following same steps.